# Not able to install npm for macOS Mojave Version 10.14.5

Tags: macos, npm

I want to install `create-react-native-app` to start a react native project. But getting following error.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should try with `sudo` command to execute npm

Comment: yeah, i think @amrs-tech is right.

Comment: use sudo npm install to install global packages with permission as the terminal clearly shows that permissions are denied. also download the latest node packager from node.js site or from watchman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` folder does not belongs to your user

There is 2 options over there:

- Using `sudo` to install the global npm packages
- Changing the ownership of the folder `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` to your current user (with `sudo chown -R YOURUSER:staff /usr/local/lib/node_modules`)